# Html template with ngIf

Tags: angular

```
<section [ngClass]="classSelector()"> 
        <ng-template [ngIf]="turn=0" [ngIfElse]="O">
            <p>Player <span>X</span>'s turn</p>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #O>
            <p>Player <span>O</span>'s turn</p>
        </ng-template>
</section>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.scss']
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
  turn:number = 0;

  classSelector = () => {
    let turnList = {
      playerX: this.turn = 1,
      playerO: this.turn = 0
    }
    return turnList
  }
  
  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Hey, I'm trying to show a p tag based on the value of "turn", but i get this error
"
src/app/index/index.component.html:6:30 - error NG5002: Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 6 in [turn=0] in /Users/hcl/Documents/Angular/clickProgram/src/app/index/index.component.html@5:29

6         <ng-template [ngIf]="turn=0" [ngIfElse]="O">
"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the correct syntax for ngIf

Use like this instead

```
<ng-template *ngIf="turn === 0">
```